# Creating digital persona fingerprint template from serialized data

Tags: delphi, activex, fingerprint, biometrics

*This is a very specific question which will probably earn me the tumbleweed badge, but please answer if you can*

I've imported DigitalPersona sdk dll's as type libraries into Delphi and am trying to verify fingerprints which I've stored as serialized data in a database, it's working very awesomely.  Enrollment seems to work fine, but I can't turn the binary data from the finger prints back into DPFPTemplate objects. I keep getting an OLEException every time I try to used the defaultinterface property of a TDPFPTemplate object.

What I'm wondering is how Digital Persona expects you to use their SDK to recreate fingerprints. This is what their instructions say:

```
1. *Retrieve serialized fingerprint template data from a fingerprint data storage subsystem.
2. Deserialize a DPFPTemplate object by calling the Deserialize method (VB page 40, C++
page 83).
3. Return a DPFPTemplate object.
```

All the ways of making a DPFPTemplate seem to only include using the fingerprint reader itself.

Here's one way that doesn't work

```
 Result := CreateOleObject('DPFPShrX.DPFPTemplate.1') as IDPFPTemplate;
 Result.Deserialize(string(AUserFinRecPtr.FingerBuffer));
```

and here's another

```
DPFPTemplate := TDPFPTemplate.Create(nil);
DPFPTemplate.DefaultInterface.Deserialize(String(AUserFinREcPtr.FingerBuffer));
```

Comment: Could you pop up some code to help give us a clue?

Comment: What is the ErrorCode (HRESULT) that the EOleException returns? And as ChrisBD says, give some code.

Comment: Error code = -2147352568, that didn't make a whole lot of sense, but I did try catching the EOleException and the message said 'Bad Variable Type'.  Maybe I'm passing in the wrong sort of thing to this function.    procedure Deserialize(RawData: OleVariant);   It's supposed to take binary data and generate a finger print template object which I can verify another finger print against.

Comment: OK, thanks commenter dudes. I think the error actually comes from the stuff I'm passing into the Deserialize function.  The 'Bad Variable Type' now I've got to figure out how to get good data.

Comment: -2147352568 = 0x80020008 = Bad Variable Type. What is the type that TDPFPTemplate.Deserialize expects and what is the type of AUserFinREcPtr.FingerBuffer? And what Delphi version are you on?

Comment: Using Delphi 7,  AUserFinRecPtr.FingerBuffer is a PAnsiChar.

Comment: The deserialize function expects something of type OleVariant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a pdf document where the Deserialize method is feaded a byte array. Your FingerBuffer is a PAnsiChar, which is an array of bytes. But then you cast it to a string which is automatically converted to an OleString (Delphi converts a string to an OleString when you assign it to an OleVariant). So you don't have an array of bytes anymore.

What you can try to do (I won't garantee it :) ):

```
var
  lByteArray: Variant;
  lArrayPointer: Pointer;
  lStr: AnsiString;
  DPFPTemplate: TDPFPTemplate;
begin
  lStr := AUserFinREcPtr.FingerBuffer;
  lByteArray := VarArrayCreate([0, Length(lStr) - 1], varByte );
  lArrayPointer:= VarArrayLock(lByteArray);
  try
    Move( lStr[1], lArrayPointer^, Length(lStr) );
  finally
    VarArrayUnlock(lByteArray);
  end;
  DPFPTemplate := TDPFPTemplate.Create(nil);
  DPFPTemplate.DefaultInterface.Deserialize(lByteArray);
```