# How to serialize fingerprinter Digital Persona in Delphi

Tags: delphi, serialization, fingerprint

I need to save a Template.Serialize in a Blob Field, How do it?

var
  s : string;
....
  s := Templ.Serialize;  --- > size less that 1632 bytes Whay?

Comment: What is `Template`? Its `Serialize` function clearly returns a string, so why not just use an ordinary string field instead of BLOB?

Comment: @Juan Carlos: You've given absolutely no information to use to help you, I'm afraid. As Rob said, what is `Template`, where except in the first sentence do you reference a blob field, and what do you expect s to contain? (You only mention that it's less than 1632 bytes - did you expect 1633, or something else?) Without information, no one can help you, and you'll spend forever answering people's questions while they try and figure out what you want. It's better to provide info up front so they can provide faster, better help.

Comment: This isn't about a database. Template is probably a COM-object. See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607441/creating-digital-persona-fingerprint-template-from-serialized-data .

@Juan Carlos: please provide more info, what does the documentation say about the Serialize method? What does it return?

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on the field type in your database (not your fielddefs).  Which database system are you using and what is the field type in that database table?  Some database systems have several blob types which support different sizes.

What is the size (not length) of variable s before writing to the blob field?  If that is less than 1632, then your problem is in serialization, not a problem writing to the blob field.

Which data access controls are you using? DBX, ADO, BDE?  Post as much information as you can for a question like this.